# Can we have the name of a person who has upvoted or downvoted

Tags: discussion

Exactly as in the question. Anonymity is something people hide behind. There will be no comeback, no questioning. It's cowardly.

Or - in the absence of that, reasons for giving the downvote should be encouraged. Or do we just guess that it's 'because I disagree'.Pretty subjective and not giving room for improvement.

I'm certainly not looking for retribution, far more interested as to the mindset that prompted a downvote - or upvote.

Comment: ...and my downvote here just indicates disagreement

Comment: Should all upvotes similarly be named, and reasons given? Having gathered 20+K rep, one has to take a downvote, in my opinion. When I downvote I sometimes leave a comment, but sometimes I simply just don't agree with the answer, and then there's not much to say. Forcing unanonymous downvotes opens up for retaliation too.

Comment: Lack of anonymity enables bullying and crusades.  Hunting someone down and interrogating them over a button click is something a lot worse than "cowardly".

Comment: I believe leaving a comment is already encouraged, by a pop-up when you downvote.

Comment: To be constructive, i think it would be great if down voters would clarify **upon request** ie. when someone asks about the reason for this down vote. And i don't see any problem of doing the same with up voters if anyone really chooses to question that. The spirit should be constructive, and i believe all members want to learn from each other and help each other to be better.

Answer (score 7):

No. This has been discussed art great length on many posts on MSE and the key point feed back is that is would dissuade downvotes.

The balance is very much in favour of doing whatever encourages up or down votes.

If people want to comment, they can, but SE has stated that we will not enforce that.